# type annotations for csv.DictWriter

Tags: python, mypy

I have trouble typo annotation csv.DictWriter. I am using mypy 0.910 and python 3.9.9.

```py
def csv_bytes_from_dict_list(dict_list: List[Dict[str, Union[str, int]]]) -> bytes:
    with TextIOWrapper(BytesIO(), encoding="utf-8") as r:
        w = DictWriter(r, fieldnames=dict_list[0].keys(), quotechar='"', quoting=QUOTE_ALL)
        w.writeheader()
        w.writerows(dict_list)
        r.flush()
        r.buffer.seek(0)
        b = r.buffer.read()
    return b
```

Mypy is showing the below errors. I am not sure how to fix them.

```sh
test.py: note: In function "csv_bytes_from_dict_list":
test.py:10:13: error: Need type annotation for "w"  [var-annotated]
            w = DictWriter(r, fieldnames=dict_list[0].keys(), quotechar='"', quoting=QUOTE_ALL)
                ^
test.py:10:38: error: Argument "fieldnames" to "DictWriter" has incompatible type "KeysView[str]"; expected "Sequence[<nothing>]"  [arg-type]
            w = DictWriter(r, fieldnames=dict_list[0].keys(), quotechar='"', quoting=QUOTE_ALL)
```

When I do

```
w: DictWriter = ...
```

I get the following error

```
error: Missing type parameters for generic type "DictWriter"
```

When I do:

```
w: DictWriter[Dict[str, Union[str, int]]] = ...
```

I get the following error.

```py
Argument 1 to "writerows" of "DictWriter" has incompatible type "List[Dict[str, Union[str, int]]]"; expected "Iterable[Mapping[Dict[str, Union[str, int]], Any]]"
```

As for the list, the following doesn't help.

```
fieldnames=list(dict_list[0])
```

It shows

```
Argument 1 to "list" has incompatible type "Dict[str, Union[str, int]]"; expected "Iterable[Dict[str, Union[str, int]]]"  [arg-type]
                r, fieldnames=list(dict_list[0]), quotechar='"', quoting=QUOTE_ALL
```

Comment: A keys view is indeed _not_ a sequence, it's not subscriptable. Given that you iterate over keys by default anyway, maybe `fieldnames=list(dict_list[0])`?

Comment: `w: DictWriter = DictWriter ...` for the first one?

Comment: The second one seems to be a CSV type issue: using a KeysView works fine (afaict), but the argument is typed as a sequence. Creating an extra list, as suggested above, avoids the typing error, but seems illogical: I would have thought an iterable would suffice.

Comment: `w: DictWriter` didnt work I have tried that already. Would also be strange if that was required as python does type inference in such sitations. I feel like it should be a DictWriter of a certain type. Something like `DictWriter[MyTypedDict]`

Comment: I get `error: Missing type parameters for generic type "DictWriter"`  when I do `w: DictWriter`

Comment: Interesting: I do get your error with `w = DictWriter(...`, but `w: DictWriter = DictWriter(...` does not produce an error. This is for Python 3.9.8 and MyPy 0.190.

Comment: As for the `fieldnames` related error: a look at the `csv` source doesn't show any typing, so MyPy is inferring a sequence from the code, while it should infer an iterable. At a first glance, it would seem MyPy is wrong here.

Comment: The typeshed [currently](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/506be4fb0adcf38af77325258af337772abcde77/stdlib/csv.pyi#L89-L98) says it should be a _collection_, which keys views _are_.

Comment: What are the versions of mypy and Python that you are using?

Comment: I am using `mypy 0.910`

Comment: @9769953 I found out how to type the DictWriter properly. It should be the type of the keys only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So by playing around with the typing of the DictWriter, I noticed that whatever type I stick in there will show as the expected type for the first type of the write rows method, essentially the key of the mapping.

For example

```py
# if w is typed like this
w: DictWriter[Dict[str, Union[str, int]]
# the arguments for w.writerows expects this type
Iterable[Mapping[Dict[str, Union[str, int]], Any]]

# if the type for w is
w: DictWriter[dict]
# the expected type for w.writerows is 
Iterable[Mapping[Dict[Any, Any], Any]]
```

Based on that, I came to the conclusion that the type for the DictWriter should be the type of the keys in the mapping.

```
# only the type of the keys
w: DictWriter[str]
# now the expected type for w.writerows also makes sense
# althogh its showing 'Any' as second type. I am not sure how to impove that
Iterable[Mapping[str, Any]]
```

That combined with `list(dict_list[0])` solves the typing errors.

```py
w: DictWriter[str] = DictWriter(r, fieldnames=list(dict_list[0]), ...)
```